# jQuery ajax asyncrhonous calling

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to make some actions after an ajax call done with jquery.

I have seen that if i use a function like this:

```
    function DownloadData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/AlbumsRest",
            accepts: "application/json",
            cache: false,
            success: function () {
                /*binding stuff*/
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error' + textStatus);
            }
        });
    }
```

The ajax request it's done in async mode. I don't want to change it because i don't want to freeze the page. But i would like to make some actions (animations, effects etc) after this ajax is completed.

So, my question is, how can i to know if i'm at the end of this request without using the success event

If i call DownloadData function like this:

```
    function DownloadNextData() {
        DownloadData();
        SlideOutAnimation();
        SlideInAnimation();
    }
```

I need to make slides after async request has been made.

Some idea ?

Comment: Have you tried complete instead of success

Comment: @SridharNarasimhan `complete` is done for both success and failure (and is also deprecated)

Comment: Why not in the success callback?

Comment: @eveevans "success" callbacks are the old crappy way of doing this - Deferred objects and `.done` are far more powerful.

Comment: @eveevans see here for relevant details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436327/jquery-deferreds-and-promises-then-vs-done

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried with .done and this works for me

Answer (score 4):

Using jQuery [Deferred Objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) you should `return` the result of `$.ajax()` from `DownloadData`

```
function DownloadData() {
    return $.ajax({...});
}
```

and then you can register a function outside of your AJAX handler that'll only get called once the AJAX call has completed:

```
function DownloadNextData() {
    DownloadData().done(function() {
        SlideOutAnimation();
        SlideInAnimation();
    });
}
```

behold - your animation processing is completely decoupled from your AJAX function :)

To simplify things, `.done` can also actually take a list of function references:

```
function DownloadNextData() {
    DownloadData().done(SlideOutAnimation, SlideInAnimation);
}
```

Note that in this case you can't supply your own function arguments - they'll actually get passed the contents of the AJAX data.

Answer (score 2):

```
function DownloadData() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "/api/AlbumsRest",
        accepts: "application/json"
    });
}

function DownloadNextData() {
    SlideOutAnimation();
    SlideInAnimation();
}

DownloadData().done(DownloadNextData);
```

Comment: Why did you leave `DownloadData` inside `DownloadNextData`?

Comment: @Alnitak - I assumed from the code in the question it just calls the ajax function once more, but I could be mistaken? Actually I think I get it now, and I'll remove it!

Answer (score -1):

Try $.ajaxcomplete. here is the documentation for it http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/