# jquery $.when() difference between .then() and .done()

Tags: jquery

I am trying to understand the difference between

```
$.when(...).then(...)

$.when(...).done(...)
```

in jQuery. As far as I understood both of them executes when objects inside when are finished loading. But what is the difference. Examples will be really appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery deferreds and promises - .then() vs .done()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436327/jquery-deferreds-and-promises-then-vs-done)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`.done()` has only success callback.

`.then()` has both success and fail callbacks.

> As of jQuery 1.8, the `deferred.then()` method returns a new promise
>   that can filter the status and values of a deferred through a
>   function, replacing the now-deprecated `deferred.pipe()` method.
>
> The `deferred.done()` method accepts one or more arguments, all of which
>   can be either a single function or an array of functions.
>
> Since `deferred.done()` returns the deferred object, other methods of
>   the deferred object can be chained to this one, including additional
>   `.done()` methods. When the Deferred is resolved, doneCallbacks are
>   executed using the arguments provided to the resolve or resolveWith
>   method call in the order they were added.

Comment: yes, you can use it for fail callback. deferred.then( doneCallbacks, failCallbacks )

Comment: This isn't really correct. Yes, `.then()` has a method signature that allows passing a fail callback as well as a success one. The more important point is that `.then()` returns a **new** promise object, `.done()` returns the same promise object. That's the basic answer at least. For a more complete answer see the answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436327/jquery-deferreds-and-promises-then-vs-done) as linked by Raphael to the original question

Comment: A very important difference is what @Anduril commented just above. With `then()` you get a new promise so you can chain different actions. Using this your code can be simplified A LOT.

Comment: @Anduril you should make your comment an answer since it contains very important concept.

Comment: @Benj at the time perhaps I should have, but Gurpreet has since edited his answer with more information which helps clarify it, and I think it might muddy the water. For now I will leave it as a comment on the original answer