# Removing a DOM element from an element which is generated by an external script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Within a page, I have third-party ad content that is generated by an external script. This content takes a little while to load. I would like to remove a line break from the ad content - to do so, it's necessary to wait until the external script has loaded and all of the functions called within that script have stopped running. I was tinkering with the following idea, but I guess it only waits until the external script is loaded:

```
$.getScript( "http://www.external_site.com/widget.js").done( function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
     $('.result').find('br').remove();  
});
```

What's the best way to wait until the external script performs all of its DOM manipulations, before calling the .remove() function?

Comment: do you have control over the external site script? You could trigger an event on completion that you could then base your removal script on.

Comment: @gautsch - unfortunately, there does not appear to be anything in/about the external script which I can manipulate, except for a few parameters to customize the ads (query, location, etc.).

Comment: Just to clarify: Is your ad loaded into an iframe?

Comment: @jmargolisvt It's not loaded in an iframe. The ad consists of a link, a line break, and a couple of spans, embedded in some divs.

Comment: Does external `js` define any object at `window` ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196617/jquery-getscript-load-vs-execution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach seems to be listening for the `onreadystatechange` and `load` events being fired from the newly-created and inserted `<script>` elements, in which the JavaScript is run.

This works in the linked (simple) demo, but I can't attest to its reliability for large projects:

```
// listening for the onreadystatechange and/or load
// events fired from the newly-added "script" elements:
$('script').on('onreadystatechange load', function (e) {
    // performs the following simple/contrived functionality:
    $('body').find('br').remove();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vabf2L9h/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`readystatechange` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/readystatechange).
- JS Fiddle:

  - [Echo JavaScript File and XHR requests](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html).
- jQuery:

  - [`jQuery.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/).

Comment: if the loaded script involve async computations, then you ll need to add a watcher in load event. This watcher would test document until if find a proof the computations finished. At that moment, the unecessary can be removed.

Comment: That takes care of it. Thanks!