# JQuery .when .done seems to cause code to run before script is done loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

After replacing hard-coded `<script>` with JQuery promises, I've been frequently getting these errors:

[image]

Reproducing the problem is inconsistent. Occasionally, the page will load without the error, which seems to happen if I keep pressing the refresh button, rather than re-loading the page from a new tab.

Here is a minimal version of the code that demonstrates the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src=//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js></script>
<script>
  $(makemap());

  var pins = [
    {
      "lng": -79.9133742,
      "lat": 43.2594723,
      "id": 544
    },
    {
      "lng": -79.9239563,
      "lat": 43.2585329,
      "id": 545
    },
    {
      "lng": -79.92670809999998,
      "lat": 43.2580113,
      "id": 546
    },
  ];

  function makemap() {
    $.when(
      $('<link/>', {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.css'
      }).appendTo('head'),
      $('<link/>', {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/0.4.0/MarkerCluster.Default.css'
      }).appendTo('head'),
      $.getScript("//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.js"),
      $.getScript("//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/0.4.0/leaflet.markercluster-src.js"),
      $.Deferred(function (deferred) {
        $(deferred.resolve);
      })
    ).done(function () {
      var tiles = L.tileLayer('//{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          maxZoom: 18,
          attribution: '&copy; <a href=http://osm.org/copyright>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }),
        latlng = L.latLng(43.26, -79.92);

      var map = L.map('map', {center: latlng, zoom: 14, layers: [tiles]});

      var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
      var markerList = [];

      for (var i of pins) {
        var marker = L.marker(L.latLng(i.lat, i.lng), {title: i.id});
        marker.placeid = i.id;
        markers.addLayer(marker);
        markerList.push(marker);
      }
      map.addLayer(markers);
    })
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? If this is a limitation of JQuery, are there any alternative methods to accomplish what I want to do here (preferably using native ES6 or below)?

---

Attemp #2 with Mike's code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel=stylesheet href=//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.css>
  <link rel=stylesheet href=//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/0.4.0/MarkerCluster.Default.css>
  <style>
    #map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src=//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js></script>
<script>
  var pins = [
    {
      "lng": -79.9133742,
      "lat": 43.2594723,
      "id": 544
    },
    {
      "lng": -79.9239563,
      "lat": 43.2585329,
      "id": 545
    },
    {
      "lng": -79.92670809999998,
      "lat": 43.2580113,
      "id": 546
    },
  ];

  var scripts = [
    "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.js",
    "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/0.4.0/leaflet.markercluster-src.js"
  ];

  var loaded = scripts.length;

  function checkDone() {
    loaded = loaded - 1;
    if (loaded === 0) {
      var tiles = L.tileLayer('//{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          maxZoom: 18,
          attribution: '&copy; <a href=http://osm.org/copyright>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }),
        latlng = L.latLng(43.26, -79.92);

      var map = L.map('map', {center: latlng, zoom: 14, layers: [tiles]});

      var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
      var markerList = [];

      for (var i of pins) {
        var marker = L.marker(L.latLng(i.lat, i.lng), {title: i.id});
        marker.placeid = i.id;
        markers.addLayer(marker);
        markerList.push(marker);
      }
      map.addLayer(markers);
    }
  }

  while (scripts.length) {
    var head = scripts.splice(0, 1)[0];
    $.getScript(head, checkDone);
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please also show where in your page this code is run: don't show your entire page HTML, just show the parts that are involved in this script, and where in the `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>` etc you're loading stuff.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I thought this problem was gone, but it's not, just inconsistent to reproduce. I've created a minimal version of the code that demonstrates the problem in the OP.

Comment: Why dont you use simple jquery, .done methods, it always worked for me

Comment: @ARUNEdathadan Isn't that what I'm doing right now, with `.when` and `.done`? TBH I don't entirely understand how these promises work...

Comment: @DavidTan updated my answer based on the commends left on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered, the heart of problem with `jQuery.getScript()` is that :

- it reliably fires its callback (or chained .then()) to indicate that the script has loaded, but
- there's no guarantee that the loaded script has executed

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34021972/3478010) the issue should be fixed in jQuery 2.1.0+, however, from what you say, that would appear not to be the case.

To give the scripts greater chance to have executed, execution of the map/marker code needs to be pushed later by some unknown small amount.

Here are some things to *try* - no better than that I'm afraid.

First give the seconmd script more time to load by splitting `checkDone()` into two functions as follows :

```
function makeMap() {
    var map = L.map('map', {
        center: L.latLng(43.26, -79.92), 
        zoom: 14, 
        layers: [L.tileLayer('//{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: '&copy; <a href=http://osm.org/copyright>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        })]
    });
    setTimeout(makeMarkers.bind(map), 0);
}
function makeMarkers() {
    var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
    pins.forEach(function(pin) {
        var marker = L.marker(L.latLng(pin.lat, pin.lng), { title: pin.id });
        marker.placeid = pin.id;
        markers.addLayer(marker);
    });
    this.addLayer(markers);
}
```

Note that `makeMarkers()` is called from `makeMap()` via a timeout. Even with a timeout of `0`, the call will occur in a later event thread.

Now, with those two functions in palce, progressively replace the `while (scripts.length) {...}` loop with :

```
$.when.apply(null, scripts.map(function(url) {
    return $.getScript(url);
})).then(makeMap);
```

then with :

```
scripts.reduce(function(promise, url) {
    return promise.then(function() {
        return $.getScript(url);
    });
}, $.when()).then(makeMap);
```

then with :

```
scripts.reduce(function(promise, url) {
    return promise.then(function() {
        return $.getScript(url);
    });
}, $.when()).then(function() {
    setTimeout(makeMap, 0);
});
```

then with :

```
scripts.reduce(function(promise, url) {
    return promise.then(function() {
        return $.getScript(url);
    });
}, $.when()).then(function() {
    setTimeout(makeMap, 1000);
});
```

At some stage, you should hopefully find that one of these processes (or maybe the last version with even more delay) fires `makeMap` late enough to be reliable - on your browser/computer under prevailing conditions.

You still have uncertainty over other browsers and other computers ....

Ultimately, you may need to revert to hard-coced script tags and accept the greater page-load time. What would be nice is for the `<SCRIPT>` tag's `defer` attribute to be reliably supported in all browsers.

Comment: The second solution worked 20/20 times on my system. But, if I understood how this all works correctly, then theoretically even a timeout of 1000 may not be enough for a very slow system. So I'm thinking, why not just loop try-catch until the map loads properly (would that be possible)?

Comment: @DavidTan, that's effectively what Mike'Pomax'Kamermans suggests. I only posted my answer because you had not accepted his answer and I assumed it had not worked for you.

Comment: If my second solution works for you, then it's possible it is a universal solution - ie it *may* work on all computers. Trouble is, I can't find anything on the web to confirm that. You would need to test-test-test to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. you're missing a master `$( function doThisOnDocumentReady() { ... })` wrapper around your code. Right now it'll kick in *immediately* rather than waiting for the DOM to be done first. That's not super critical here, but it's good practice and a good habit to get into (you can pretty much ignore this advice if you just want this problem solved though)
2. `getScript` itself does not wait for resources linked in those nodes to finish "all the way" before returning. You can give it a callback to trigger after it finishes loading the script, but that still doesn't guarantee the scrip's finished executing, too. As such, right now your code runs before we are technically guaranteed that the things you need are actually available.

So, instead of hoping they're reading, let's explicitly make sure they're ready before we run the code that relies on having leaflet etc. properly set up:

```
function doStuffKnowingItllWork() {
  // ... your actual code ...
}

$.when() {
  // ... load scripts etc here ...
).done(function () {

  // ensure we have everything available
  (function ensureDependencies() {
    if (window.L) {
      return setTimeout(doStuffKnowingItllWork,0);
    }
    setTimeout(ensureDependencies, 200);
  }());
});
```

This sets up a function that checks whether we have what we need to do the work we need to do (in the case of leaflet, a global `L` variable) and if it's not available, we schedule a call to the same function (at least) 200 milliseconds from now.

If we do have all the dependencies we need, we schedule a call to the "actually run the code you need", with a fresh execution context and callstack by scheduling it on the next tick, using setTimeout 0 - you could just `return doStuffKnowingItllWork();`, but then if there's an error your stack trace is going to include the dependency check and jquery wrapping.

Also note that this is a function that immediately gets called after declaring, and that there is some syntax freedom: both `(function x(){})()` and `(function x(){}())` do the same; where you put that execution operator (the `()` part that runs a function) is mostly up to you and what JS style you want to follow. Also note it's functionally equivalent to `function x(){}; x();` so if you want to use that for clarity: also up to you.

Comment: I was previously using `<link>` and `<script>` for this, the Jquery is to save requests when the user doesn't select to use the map [Single page app]. It works 100%, but again I'd be going backwards if I went back to that. I tried your solution with the counter, the page loads correctly about half the time on new page loads where it previously never worked unless refreshing, but still gets the same error the other half of the time.

Comment: #1 in this answer isn't important in this particular case. I certainly wouldn't say always use it regardless either... with the code at the bottom, waiting for dom ready only delays code execution with no real benefit.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't wait for the resources? According to [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/), `$.getScript` is a shorthand for a `$.ajax` call which does return a promise. And btw, the `$.when` also waits for a deferred that resolves on document-ready, see the last argument.

Comment: @Bergi unfortunately: very sure. To quote the docs: " The callback is fired once the script has been loaded but not necessarily executed." so technically this solution isn't fail safe either, although slightly better. I guess a setTimeout bootstrap function until we are guaranteed to have what we need might be the true solution here.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I tried the new solution and it's still not working consistently. But on a similar line to your idea: would it be possible to catch this error, and try to run the code again each time the error occurs?

Comment: @DavidTan it would, but this code *should* run consistently (although the code here only checks for `L` so if you rely on more than that, you need to test for more things). And better way to make sure things "just work" is to combine this approach with calling `runMyActualCode(L, ...)` and having all your own code run through that function, with the leaflet etc. dependencies passed down explicitly rather than trying to access them from global context.

Comment: "... if you rely on more than that ..." ... if I understand correctly, you need also to test for `L.markerClusterGroup`, which is a plugin loaded via the second of the two scripts.

Answer (score -2):

Call Jquery before leaflet.js
and $.when( in document.ready

Comment: What do you mean by "call Jquery"?