# jQuery - fire AJAX callback after script has been loaded AND executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm running into an issue where I need to AJAX load some scripts, and only once the scripts have been both loaded and parsed/executed, should the callback function should fire.

It appears that ajax requests will fire the callback as soon as the script is downloaded, but not necessarily when it's been executed. Is there a way to do this other than mucking around with Timeouts and such?

```
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'script',
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            url: 'http://example.com/script1.js'
        }).success(function () {
            // I need this callback to fire only once the script has been executed
        });
```

Comment: Well you could declare a Global variable `myGlobalVar = 0` outside `script1.js` and then your script1.js modify its value to 1. Then on your `.success` callback you could put a `while ( myGlobalVar == 0 )` .... until it is 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your should look in to jquerys *when*

Will allow you to execute code after multiple async (ajax) methods are done executing.

From the jquery documentation:

> Description: Provides a way to execute callback functions based on one
>   or more objects, usually Deferred objects that represent asynchronous
>   events.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

**as for the scripts to execute before running code, jquery has a solution for this; getScripts**

```
$.getScript("jquery.cookie.js")
    .done(function() {
        jQuery.cookie("cookie_name", "value", { expires: 7 });
});
```

Load multiple scripts and execute them before running your code by combining *getScript* and *when*

```
$.when(
    $.getScript( "/script1.js" ),
    $.getScript( "/script2.js" ),
    $.Deferred(function( deferred ){
        $( deferred.resolve );
    })
).done(function(){

    // your code

});
```

Another approach:

```
var scripts = ['script1.js','script2.js','script3.js'];
$.getScript(scripts, function(data, textStatus) {
    //do something after all scripts have loaded
});
```

Ref: http://www.sitepoint.com/getscript-mutiple-scripts/