# jquery - do something after everything is done -

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred, promise

I have a set of functions to run, in sequence, but the first one has an asynchronous sub-function.  I want the second highest-level function to run only after the async function completes.  Any idea how I do this?

File A:

```
one();
two(); // I don't want this to run until after one()'s $.ajax success callback
```

---

```
function one() {
    doSomethingElse();
    $.ajax(url, {data: data}, function(){
        // do two();
    });
}
```

Comment: Why dont you just call the two() at the `success` method of the $.ajax?

Comment: you could also add `async: false` to your ajax call if you don't want it to run asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to return the AJAX object:

```
function one() {
    doSomethingElse();

    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: data
    });
}
```

And now you do:

```
one().done(function() {
    two();
});
```

It's a little cleaner than putting `two()` directly into the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Promises are the best option for your purposes

[jQuery deferreds and promises - .then() vs .done()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436327/jquery-deferreds-and-promises-then-vs-done)

Answer (score 0):

```
function one() {
    doSomethingElse();
    $.ajax(url, {data: data}, function(){
        // do two();
        two();
    });
}

function two(){
alert("here");
}
```