# Ajax promise error "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" despite returning a promise

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise

I'm trying to use a function to initialize datas with 3 ajax calls, and when this function is done I want to do something with the datas. I have to wait for the 3 ajax calls to be done before I can return a promise. The thing is, if I wait for the 3 ajax calls to be done (with $.when (ajax1, ajax2, ajax3).done(...)), I get the error "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Here is my code

```
function myInit() {
    initData().then(function() {
        console.log("a");
    });
}

function initData() {
    var results = {
        categories: [],
        commandes: [],
        users: []
    };
    var ajaxCategories = $.ajax({
        url: url + '/categorie/getAll',
        success: function(data) {
            results.categories = data;
        }
    });

    var ajaxCommandes = $.ajax({
        url: url + '/statistique/getSimpleCommandes',
        success: function(data) {
            results.commandes = data;
        }
    });
    var ajaxUsers = $.ajax({
        url: url + '/statistique/getSimpleUsers',
        success: function(data) {
            results.users = data;
        }
    });
    $.when(ajaxUsers, ajaxCommandes, ajaxCategories)
        .done(function() {
            results.commandes.forEach(function(commande) {
                results.users.forEach(function(user) {
                    if (user.id == commande.user)
                        commande.user = user.nom;
                });
            });
            return $.Deferred().resolve();
        });
}
```

I return a promise in the $.when. If I move this return outside of the when, it works fine, but then I risk getting out of the function and continuing my code with the datas not loaded. Where is my mistake?

Comment: I don't see any `return` in `initData` - `initData()` does *not* return a promise.

Comment: You'll need to use `.then` not `.done` if you want to `return` something from the callback.

Comment: When asking for help, please take the time to ensure your code is readably and reasonably formatted. The above is not. *Edit*: *Was* not, I've fixed it for you.

Comment: Thanks, I actually wondered why it was already fixed when I tried to edit it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`initData()` does not return a promise, as there is no `return` statement in that function. You'll need to return the promise that `$.when` gives you.

Also to chain an action and return something from the callback, you'll need to use `.then` not `.done`:

```
function initData() {
    var results = {
        categories: [],
        commandes: [],
        users: []
    };
    var ajaxCategories = $.ajax({
        url: url + '/categorie/getAll',
        success: function(data) {
            results.categories = data;
        }
    });

    var ajaxCommandes = $.ajax({
        url: url + '/statistique/getSimpleCommandes',
        success: function(data) {
            results.commandes = data;
        }
    });
    var ajaxUsers = $.ajax({
        url: url + '/statistique/getSimpleUsers',
        success: function(data) {
            results.users = data;
        }
    });
    return $.when(ajaxUsers, ajaxCommandes, ajaxCategories)
//  ^^^^^^
    .then(function() {
//   ^^^^
        results.commandes.forEach(function(commande) {
            results.users.forEach(function(user) {
                if (user.id == commande.user)
                    commande.user = user.nom;
            });
        });
        return results; // I guess that is what you wanted
    });
}
```

You might even further advance this by not using a global `results` variable, but make it local to your callback:

```
function initData() {
    return $.when(
        $.get(url + '/categorie/getAll'), 
        $.get(url + '/statistique/getSimpleCommandes'),
        $.get(url + '/statistique/getSimpleUsers')
    ).then(function(categoriesRes, commandesRes, userRes) {
        var results = {
            categories: categoriesRes[0],
            commandes: commandesRes[0],
            users: userRes[0]
        };
        results.commandes.forEach(function(commande) {
            results.users.forEach(function(user) {
                if (user.id == commande.user)
                    commande.user = user.nom;
            });
        });
        return results;
    });
}
```

Comment: How can I use the value returned by then? I don't quite understand if it returns a promise or my results

Comment: No, you don't need to use `.then` instead of `.done`. In your example `.then` does exactly the same as `.done`.

Comment: @Percee: It returns a promise for the results - they will be available as an argument to further callbacks. for example `initData.then(function(res) { console.log(res.commandes); })`

Comment: @Guffa: Since I `return` from my callback it does indeed make a large difference. You can try it out yourself, or have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436327/jquery-deferreds-and-promises-then-vs-done

Comment: @Bergi: Neat, you're right. I won't have to stock it in window.data now :)

Comment: @Percee: Yes, that how promises are supposed to work - no global data variables of unknown state any more :-)

Comment: @Bergi: What do you think is the difference between `.done(callback)` and `.then(callback)`?

Comment: @Guffa: The result. `done` returns the original promise, while `.then(callback)` returns a new promise that resolves with the result of the `callback`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: @Guffa: Yes, I know that antipattern ([obviously](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25569299/1048572)). Why did you point me to it?

Comment: @Bergi: Because you are recommending it.

Comment: @Guffa: Yes, I recommend to avoid it, but I didn't link it because I don't think the OP intended to use it.

Comment: @Bergi: No,  you are recommending to use it.

Comment: @Guffa: Where would I do so? I almost never use deferreds.

Answer (score 0):

Returning a promise from the callback for `done` doesn't make the `initData` function return anything.

Create the promise outside the `$.when` call so that you can resolve it in the callback and return it from `initData`:

```
var promise = $.Deferred();
$.when(ajaxUsers, ajaxCommandes, ajaxCategories)
    .done(function(){
        results.commandes.forEach(function(commande){
            results.users.forEach(function(user){
                if (user.id == commande.user)
                    commande.user = user.nom;
            });
        });
        promise.resolve();
    });
return promise.promise();
```

Alternatively, return the promise that `done` returns:

```
return $.when(ajaxUsers, ajaxCommandes, ajaxCategories)
    .done(function(){
        results.commandes.forEach(function(commande){
            results.users.forEach(function(user){
                if (user.id == commande.user)
                    commande.user = user.nom;
            });
        });
    });
```

The handlers added using the `done` method are called in the order that they are added, so any handlers that the caller adds will run after your handler.

If you want to pass on data from your `done` handler in the promise that you return, you send it in the `resolve` call:

```
var promise = $.Deferred();
$.when(ajaxUsers, ajaxCommandes, ajaxCategories)
    .done(function(){
        results.commandes.forEach(function(commande){
            results.users.forEach(function(user){
                if (user.id == commande.user)
                    commande.user = user.nom;
            });
        });
        promise.resolve(results);
    });
return promise.promise();
```

Comment: `return promise;` => `return promise.promise();` We don't want to expose the full `Deferred` API to the caller. Of course, `$.when` returns a promise already.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: Thanks, it works. I read in the link provided by Bergi that Deferred should only be used when I have no other choice. Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do in this piece of code, without using $.Deferred directly?

Comment: @Percee: You can also use the promise that the `$.when` method creates, and the `done` method returns.