# Trigger custom event after html() set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a response handler that replaces content from ajax response.  I want to fire an event after the content is replaced.  This is the response handler:

```
function(response)
    {
        /* animate to top if called from bottom pagination */
        if ( caller === 'pag-bottom' && jq('#subnav').length ) {
            var top = jq('#subnav').parent();
            jq('html,body').animate({scrollTop: top.offset().top}, 'slow', function() {
                jq(target).fadeOut( 100, function() {
                    jq(this).html(response);
                    jq(this).fadeIn(100);
                });
            });

        } else {
            jq(target).fadeOut( 100, function() {
                jq(this).html(response);
                jq(this).fadeIn(100);
            });
        }
        jq('.item-list-tabs li.selected').removeClass('loading');
     // the event I want to trigger
        jq( document ).trigger( "buddyFilter:replaced", [ object, filter] );
    }
```

My problem is this event fires to early so my code that fires on event doesn't calculate the size of the div correctly and formatting is incorrect.

I have tried various combinations of trying to chain the event trigger but I can't get it right.  I can't use a manual delay because then that will cause visual jump and not always work if loading time is slower than time.

How can I trigger this event the moment the html() value has rendered?

Edit:

Here is jsfiddle that is similar to my code but I had to change it about to get to work in fiddle.  It shows that right after the event fires the div is 0 height

http://jsfiddle.net/jq7n4kfL/1/

Comment: Why not trigger the event once the animation is complete --- in the last `fadeOut`s callback?

Comment: I tried `jq(this).fadeIn(100).trigger( "buddyFilter:replaced", [ object, filter] );` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try utilizing `.promise()` , `.then()`

```
    function success(response)
        {
            /* animate to top if called from bottom pagination */
            if ( caller === 'pag-bottom' && jq('#subnav').length ) {
                var top = jq('#subnav').parent();
                return jq('html,body').animate({scrollTop: top.offset().top}, 'slow', function() {
                    jq(target).fadeOut( 100, function() {
                        jq(this).html(response);
                        jq(this).fadeIn(100);
                        jq('.item-list-tabs li.selected').removeClass('loading');
                    });
                }).promise();

            } else {
               return jq(target).fadeOut( 100, function() {
                    jq(this).html(response);
                    jq(this).fadeIn(100);
                    jq('.item-list-tabs li.selected').removeClass('loading');
                }).promise();
            }             
        };

$.ajax().then(success).then(function() {
  // the event I want to trigger
  jq( document ).trigger( "buddyFilter:replaced", [ object, filter] );
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks!  Is there any benefit to adding return before selector?  I had a play with the fiddle and it works if I do promise().done(func) http://jsfiddle.net/jq7n4kfL/2/

Comment: @Guerrilla Included `return` to return a jQuery promise value to next `.then()` , if any , in chain. Using `.done()` should return similar results as `.then()` to call `.trigger()`.  Note, `.done()` returns original jQuery promise value , `.then()` can return a new jQuery promise value . See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436327/jquery-deferreds-and-promises-then-vs-done .

Answer (score 1):

You're triggering the event too early. Try this:

```
            jq(target).fadeOut( 100, function() {
                jq(this).html(response);
                jq(this).fadeIn(100, function() {
                   //trigger the event herer
                });
            });
```

Of course, you have to do it in two places.

Comment: It still fires too early, the content hasn't rendered in so my code gets incorrect div size.  If I add in a 1 second delay then it works (with visual jump).

Answer (score 0):

You just put the event firing right after the actual HTML replacement takes place:

```js
jq(target).fadeOut( 100, function() {
    jq(this).html(response);
    jq( document ).trigger( "buddyFilter:replaced", [ object, filter] );
    jq(this).fadeIn(100);
});
```

Also note that you repeat exactly the same code twice so better DRY it by wrapping it in a method.

Comment: It still fires too early, the content hasn't rendered in so my code gets incorrect div size.  If I add in a 1 second delay then it works (with visual jump).

Comment: Once `jq(this).html(response)` is called the content should be fully rendered before any further JS code is executed. I suggest you show a fiddle as the issue might be specific to your content or something.

Comment: here is fiddle that shows exactly what happens but I had to change the code around a bit but it highlights the issue http://jsfiddle.net/jq7n4kfL/1/

Comment: I have put the event triggering into `fadeIn` callback (as @PeterKA pointed) and it worked: http://jsfiddle.net/xs0k65vy/

Comment: Yes you are correct, I looked too hastily at the code and didn't put it correctly in the right callback.