# jQuery.when() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of asynchronous actions whose responses must be synchronized in order to run a final action. I'm using The **Deferred** object and the **when()** and **done()** methods to achieve this, but for some reason, the final action within done() is always executed when the first **resolve()** of the responses is invoked.

This is the code I have, cut a bit short to make it clearer:

```
       // Central function that creates a Deferred object and returns a
       // Promise from it. when the passed request is done, 
       // the Deferred is resolved
       var getData = function(url, successFunction) {
            var deferred = $.Deferred();
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                method: 'get',
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function(p) {
                successFunction(p);
                deferred.resolve(p);
            }).fail(function(p){
                deferred.reject(p);
            });
            return deferred.promise();
        };

        // Success actions to be called for each asynchronous request

        var populateDestinations = function(data) {
            // synchronous actions on DOM
        };

        var populateTaxes = function(data) {
            // synchronous actions on DOM
        };

        var populatePayment = function(data) {
            // synchronous actions on DOM
        };


        // Actions that return a Promise to control the resolution of 
        // all the deferred objects

        var getCustomerDestinations = function(customerId) {
            var url = $modal.data('url_destinations') + customerId;
            return getData(url, populateDestinations);
        };

        var getCustomerTaxes = function(customerId) {
            var url = $modal.data('url_taxes') + customerId;
            return getData(url, populateTaxes);
        };

        var getCustomerPayment = function(customerId) {
            var url = $modal.data('url_payment') + customerId;
            return getData(url, populatePayment);
        };

        var populateFields = function() {
            // final actions
        };


        $.when(getCustomerDestinations(customer_id),
                getCustomerTaxes(customer_id),
                getCustomerPayment(customer_id))
        .done(function(){

             populateFields();

        });
```

**populateFields()** is being called whenever one of the "promised" functions is resolved, not when **all** of them are resolved.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Maybe I haven't yet grasped the concept of the Deferred object.

Comment: You are missing closing parenthesis in important places. Please add them (show us code that is not a syntax error).

Comment: Avoid the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)! It should be just `function getData(url, fn) { return $.getJSON(url).then(fn); }`

Comment: actually you dont need to create a deferred object to get the promise , instead just return `$.ajax()`, which will return a promise object by default. so remove all deferred objects and just return  from `$.ajax()`

Comment: I've just added the missing parenthesis.

Comment: The real error was that, despite it's not present in my cut short example  because there are more actions in the when() method, this was not enclosing all the actions. I added its closing parenthesis before. So it was a logic error. 

I've checked that this way, both my initial implementation with Deferreds, and yours just returning the $.ajax promise, will work. 

However, I'll take your advice and use you implementation, which is simpler.

Thanks both of you!

Comment: good to know, now can we close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you really dont need to use any deferred objects to track ajax calls, instead you can just use the promise object returned from `$.ajax` within `$.when()`.

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
var getData = function(url, successFunction) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: 'get',
            dataType: 'json'
        }).then(function(p) {
            successFunction(p);
        },function(p){
            //process error using error callback, 
            //just like success callbacks
        });
    };
```

I order to process individual ajax calls you can use `.then()` instead of `.done()` & `.fail()`, because these will not return any promise object unlike `.then()` to track the same in `.when()`.

Rest of your code will work as it is.

**What jQuery forum says:**

> As of **jQuery 1.8**, the `deferred.then()` method returns a new promise that can filter the status and values of a deferred through a function, replacing the now-deprecated `deferred.pipe()` method. The `doneFilter` and `failFilter` functions filter the original deferred's resolved / rejected status and values. The `progressFilter` function filters any calls to the original deferred's notify or notifyWith methods. These filter functions can return a new value to be passed along to the promise's `.done()` or `.fail()` callbacks, or they can return another observable object (Deferred, Promise, etc) which will pass its resolved / rejected status and values to the promise's callbacks.

**refence links :**

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings
- http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

Comment: You should always use `then` instead of `done` and `fail` (unless you know what you are doing)

Comment: usage is `then()` is nothing but using `done` & `fail` underneath it , so it really doesnt make a difference. here is the statement from jquery frorum for `then`, **"jqXHR.then():Incorporates the functionality of the .done() and .fail() methods, allowing (as of jQuery 1.8) the underlying Promise to be manipulated. Refer to deferred.then() for implementation details."**

Comment: It *does* make a difference (in the return value), and that's why it should be used by default. `then` is more than just `done` and `fail`. You should get used to it.

Comment: Hmmm, you got any article on this, I haven't seen any difference though.

Comment: @Bergi: thanks mate, now i understood what you meant. will updated answer as well :)

Comment: @dreamweiver Thanks for your help. Although I'm still not sure about the difference between then() and done()/fail()

Comment: prior of jquery 1.8, `.then()` was same as `done()` or `fail()` but after jQuery 1.8 `.then()` returned more than just a promise object. check this SO answer for more information.http://stackoverflow.com/a/5436869/1677272 .

Comment: Even though you code may work either way, i would suggest you to go with `.then()` , just to be future proof.