# Using $.when with Ajax requisitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to execute some $.ajax() requisitions in a certain order, so I tried to use **$.when** like this:(just for testing)

```
$.when.apply(null,[ajaxRequisition1(),ajaxRequisition2()] ).then(function () {
    console.log("Completed all requests.");
    });
```

But it shoots the message on the console before the requisitions are done. Any suggestions?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here are one of my requisitions. I'll post one, but the others are very similar, changing only some parameters.

code:

```
function ajaxRequisition1(){ 
$.ajax({
       type:'GET',
       crossDomain:true,
       url:'http://www.myurl.com.br/api/my_php.php?callbackplat=?',
       dataType:'jsonp',
       data: {currency: $('#cur').val()},
       beforeSend: function(){
           $('#loading').css("display","block");
           $('table[name=tb_latam]').css("opacity","0.01");

       }    

    }).done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            //HERE I BUILD A TABLE USING THE DATA RECEIVED.

           $('#loading').css("display","none");
           $('table[name=tb_latam]').css("opacity","1");


           $('#tb_latam').append('<tr> <td data-nome="A-ACTIVE" class="column_st">'+'Active'+
                                '</td><td class="c_qtdA column_qtd">'+data.lat_qtdA+
                                '</td><td id="a2"class="a">'+data.lat_active+
                                '</td><td>'+data.lat_p_active+'</td></tr>');


           $('#tb_latam').append('<tr> <td data-nome="I-INACTIVE" class="column_st">'+'Inactive'+
                                '</td><td class="c_qtdI column_qtd">'+data.lat_qtdI+
                                '</td><td class="i">'+data.lat_inactive+
                                '</td><td>'+data.lat_p_inactive+'</td></tr>');

           $('#tb_latam').append('<tr> <td data-nome="R-REPLACED" class="column_st">'+'Replaced'+
                                '</td><td class="c_qtdR column_qtd">'+data.lat_qtdR+
                                '</td><td  class="r">'+data.lat_replaced+
                                '</td><td>'+' - '+'</td></tr>');

    })
     .fail(function(data, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("ERROR!.");
        console.log(data);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    });
   return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jQuery $.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) accepts deferred objects. While your `ajaxRequisition` returns a `non deferred`, `$.when()` will then return a resolved promise.

Try to change your code,

```
function ajaxRequisition1 () {
    return $.ajax({
        ...
    });
}

function ajaxRequisition2 () {
    return $.ajax({
        ...
    });
}

$.when.apply(null, [ajaxRequisition1(),ajaxRequisition2()]).done(function () {
    console.log("Completed all requests.");
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I just put the `return` before `$.ajax()` and everything worked!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to use `.done(...)`.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436327/jquery-deferreds-and-promises-then-vs-done) to learn the differences.

**edit**

As per the docs of jquery, if you pass NOT-a-promise to the `.when(...)` method, the `.then(...`) will get called automatically and treat the arguments you passed to `.when(...)` as already resolved promises, and also pass them to the `.then(...)`

So, the array you're passing have to be promises so that the .`when(...)` gets called at the correct time.

> If a single argument is passed to jQuery.when() and it is not a Deferred or a Promise, it will be treated as a resolved Deferred and any doneCallbacks attached will be executed immediately.

[Check docs.](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

**edit 2**

I thought your ajaxRequisitions methods were already working. Here's the example from the docs to the `.when(...)` function

```
$.when( $.ajax( "test.aspx" ) ).then(function(
        data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    alert( jqXHR.status ); // Alerts 200
});
```

You need to update it so you can add the `.apply(...)`, and have your `ajaxRequisition`... Methods return the Ajax call you need in each one.

Comment: Hi, I changed to `.done`, but it didn't changed anything, the console message keeps coming before the requisitions finish.

Comment: Ok I see now maybe your problem is another. I'm updating answer

Comment: Uhn, okay, but the ´$.ajax()´ requisitions doesn't already return as Promisses? If not, how can I make they do? Can you give me a working example?

Comment: Can't, don't have a computer at hand, but you're not doing any Ajax request here. I'm posting an example from the docs I linked

Comment: If you could post your ajaxRequisition methods that would help to find your problem