# How to wait until a select list value has changed in jQuery

Tags: jquery

There are 5 select list in my html page. all the select list populate dynamically with a json response from a ajax call. In the ajax success function i need to set a value selected for each select list.

but changing value of select list is randomly fails for different select lists different time. I tried several way and what i found is jQuery is executing the next line when it takes time to change the value and never go to previous.

I tried change() function, ready() function, load() function etc with no success. i need to wait until the previous select list value has changed. how can i do that. here is my sample code.

```
    var jsonParam = '';
    var serviceURL = "./someurl";
    AjaxManager.SendJson(serviceURL, jsonParam, onSuccess, onFailed);
    function onSuccess(jsonData) {
        $('#cmb1').val(jsonData.Field1);
        $('#cmb2').val(jsonData.Field2);
        $('#cmb3').val(jsonData.Field3);
        $('#cmb4').val(jsonData.Field4);
        $('#cmb5').val(jsonData.Field5);
    }
```

Comment: You can chain your methods with `.then()` fucntion. https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

Comment: $('#cmb1').val(jsonData.Field1).then(function(){ $('#cmb2').val(jsonData.Field2);}). This way?

Comment: What is this AjaxManager. Is it some ASP.Net thing? Or is it a pure jquery? I searched for that, and found nothing with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `.then()`, the answer might be here:
[jQuery deferreds and promises - .then() vs .done()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436327/jquery-deferreds-and-promises-then-vs-done)

Good luck :)

Comment: when i use .then or .done it says console error : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).val(...).then is not a function

Comment: I think you are using it wrong. Take a look here: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

Comment: Deferred.then is usually works with ajax call. but do not need to chain ajax call. i have only one ajax call and within the success function, i need to chain the dropdowns change event. it should change value after changing the previous one. currently it is changing randomly. please help me to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, what is this AjaxManager thing. In jQuery, you can use `deferred.then()` and you can chain these.

So your script should be look like this:

```
var jsonParam = '';
var serviceURL = "./someurl";
$.get(serviceURL, jsonParam, function (jsonData) {
    $('#cmb1').val(jsonData.Field1);
}).then(function () {
    $('#cmb2').val(jsonData.Field2);
}).then(function () {
    $('#cmb3').val(jsonData.Field3);
}).then(function () {
    $('#cmb4').val(jsonData.Field4);
}).then(function () {
    $('#cmb5').val(jsonData.Field5);
}).fail(function {
    //Here comes to fail
});
```

Note that, I used the `$.get` method. If you need to pass your parameters to the ajax by `post` then just change `$.get` to `$.post`.

Thats it. When `$.get` gets the response, the response will be in your `jsonData` variable, and update the `#cmb1` value, then the second, and so on. Finally, if your ajax call is failed, then call the `fail` method.

**EDIT**

As you mentioned, you get error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).val(...).then is not a function

Did you imported the jQuery library on your page?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: when i use .then it says console error : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).val(...).then is not a function –

Comment: yes jQuery library in imported into my page. and still says the same error in the browser console.