# Multiple data fields aren't recognized in $.WHEN function (JQUERY, SHOPIFY)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, shopify, liquid

Basically, when I run the code below, ***cart*** and ***product*** are not recognized, and I have no idea why that is.

Here's the code:

```
$.when(
    $.getJSON(_config.shopifyAjaxCartURL),
    $.getJSON(_config.shopifyAjaxProductURL)
).then(function(cart,product){
    alert ('1 - TOTAL ITEM COUNT: ' + cart.item_count);
    for (var i = 0;  i <= cart.item_count; i++) {
        alert ('2 - LOOPING');
        if (cart.items[i].sku == product.variants[0].sku) {
            productQuantity = cart.items[i].quantity;
            alert ('3 - FOUND IT');
            return false;
        }              
    }           
    alert ('NUMBER 4');
});
```

Here are the results:

- **1:** Prompts "1 - TOTAL ITEM COUNT: ***undefined***"
- **2:** Does NOT go into loop.
- **3:** Prompts "NUMBER 4"

--

On the other hand, when I remove one of the two parameters for $.when and the function, however, it all works perfectly. For example, this would work:

```
$.when($.getJSON(_config.shopifyAjaxCartURL)).then(function(cart){  .....
```

The output would be:

- **1:** Prompts "1 - TOTAL ITEM COUNT: **92**"
- **2:** Prompts "2 - LOOPING".
- **3:** Prompts "NUMBER 4" (because it can't find `product.variants[0].sku` now).

--

Any idea of why the two parameters are conflicting? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

**EDIT:**

Update to my progress: I went ahead and removed the second parameter, so that I only make one JSON request, and only have the `cart` parameter. Since I am using scripting for Shopify (using Liquid) I went ahead and tried to use a Liquid object to get the Product SKU, instead of getting it from the Product's JSON. To my surprise, it works, as long I put the Liquid Object in quotation marks. I looks like this now:

```
 $.when($.getJSON(_config.shopifyAjaxCartURL)).done(function(cart){

          alert ('1 - TOTAL ITEM COUNT: ' + cart.item_count);                                            

          for (var i = 0;  i <= cart.item_count; i++) {     

             alert ('2 - LOOPING');

            if (cart.items[i].sku == "{{product.variants[0].sku}}") {
                productQuantity = cart.items[i].quantity;
                alert ('3 - FOUND IT');
             }

           }

          alert ('NUMBER 4');
```

**However**, although it goes through the loop perfectly now, it skips the remaining code entirely. The output is like this:

- **1:** Prompts "1 - TOTAL ITEM COUNT: **92**"
- **2:** Prompts "2 - LOOPING".
- **3:** Prompts "3 - FOUND IT!"

...... *and it never goes on to NUMBER 4.* I suspect it's because the quotation marks are commenting out the rest of the line, after "{{product.variants[0].sku}}"; it seems as though it doesn't fully count the "{{...}}" content as being between quotation marks, somehow.

Do you know why this may be?

Comment: Did you try running each of the two parameters independently, or just the first one?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried the second one independently as well, works just fine if it's by itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between using `.then` and `.done`. You are trying to use the functionality of `.done`, but you're using `.then`. I suggest trying `.done`. Also, here is some more info:

[jQuery deferreds and promises - .then() vs .done()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436327/jquery-deferreds-and-promises-then-vs-done)

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, I did try `.done` before `.then`, with the same results, I'm afraid :/

Comment: So far it is obvious that `cart` is not being passed in correctly to the loop. Still working out why that would be.

Comment: It's bizarre indeed - Is there any reason why the second parameter would make it so?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the immediate issue by putting a `break` on the `if()` clause (whereas I had previously tried `return false` in the same place). Here's how it looks:

```
    $.when($.getJSON(_config.shopifyAjaxCartURL)).done(function(cart){

      alert ('1 - TOTAL ITEM COUNT: ' + cart.item_count);                                            

      for (var i = 0;  i <= cart.item_count; i++) {     

         alert ('2 - LOOPING');

        if (cart.items[i].sku == "{{product.variants[0].sku}}") {
            productQuantity = cart.items[i].quantity;
            alert ('3 - FOUND IT');
            break;
         }

       }

      alert ('NUMBER 4');
```

Finally, the output is:

- **1:** Prompts "1 - TOTAL ITEM COUNT: 92"
- **2:** Prompts "LOOPING"
- **3:** Prompts "FOUND IT"
- **4:** Prompts "NUMBER 4"

Which works for my purposes for now, but I still don't understand why the two parameters on the `$.WHEN` function were invalidating one another. Does anyone have insight into that particular issue?