# How do I chain of 2 deferred functions and prevent third function from being executed if second is rejected in jQuery 1.8.x?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given 2 deferred functions

```
function func1() {
  var dfd = $.Deferred();

  setTimeout(function() {
    dfd.resolve('Password');
  }, 1000);

  return dfd.promise();
}

function func2(id) {
  var dfd = $.Deferred();

  if (id == 0) {
      dfd.reject();
  }
  else {
      dfd.resolve();
  }
  return dfd.promise();
 }

 function func3()
 {
    alert('Hello World')
 }
```

if func2 is rejected, I dont want func3 to be executed.

ive tried

```
func1().then(func2(1)).then(func3())
```

and

```
func1().then(func2(1)).done(func3())
```

func3() seems to be always executed.

Comment: You all times execute func3, you should path the link to the func3. for example .then(func3)

Answer (score 1):

`func1().then(func2(1)).then(func3())`

Should be:

`func1().then(function () {func2(1)}).then(func3)`

Which actually should be:

`func1().then(() => func2(1)).then(func3)`

When you send arguments to a function, the function will execute (even in the case of `()`.  So, what we need to do is prevent this.  Since `func3` takes in no arguments, we can just pass it as is into the function, no `()`.  But since we want `func2` to have arguments, we are defining a function around it.  So, you can do it via `function` or you can do it via an arrow function, `=>`.

Here's how you would check for failure.

```
func1().then(() => func2(0)).fail(() => alert("oh no")).then(func3);
```

Comment: i tried func1().then(function () {func2(0)}).then(func3) that didnt work but this func1().then(() => func2(1)).then(func3) did. Whats the difference?

Comment: The issue is in the event of 0 you don't handle the failure of the promise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436327/jquery-deferreds-and-promises-then-vs-done  . You need to add `.fail()`.  If you could upvote or mark mine as solution, that would help a lot.

Comment: IE edge does not support arrow functions. furthermore why is done executed when func2 fails?

Comment: Wait a second, are you just stringing them all together?  What's your code?

Comment: func1().then(() => func2(0)).then(func3)

Comment: I updated the code with how to handle errors.  Sorry for being rude, I realized that right after I posted it.

Comment: Sorry I meant IE 11. Getting an syntax error at the arrow function

Comment: oh, just use a normal function then.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure not to *invoke* the functions you pass to `then`. It is the jQuery deferred implementation that needs to call them, not you, so you need to pass functions, not function calls.

Secondly, if you need to have an argument passed, then you can use `.bind`, which creates a new function from an existing one, but which will pass the argument that you specify at the moment the function is called:

```
func1().then(func2.bind(null, 1)).then(func3)
       .fail(function () { console.log('failed') });
```

The first argument passed to `then` is only called when the promise is resolved, not when it is rejected. So as soon as there is a rejected promise in the chain, none of the chained `then` callbacks (first arguments) will be executed.