# Weird (or Unknown to me) Promise Syntax - Complete, Fail, Done

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I ran into the code block below...and I don't understand it. I understand promises perfectly in the sense of (and everything that goes with it):

```
deferred.then(successCb, errorCb);
```

However, the code below seems to have three callbacks(`complete`, `fail`, `done`) and I don't know where to begin looking - I can only guess an observable-like `success`, `failure`, `finally` pattern, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I checked random questions like [jQuery deferreds and promises - .then() vs .done()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436327/jquery-deferreds-and-promises-then-vs-done) and some docs like [here](https://codeplanet.io/jquery-always-done-fail-then/). The docs seem to imply that `complete` isn't even a thing and there are only `always` (runs whether promise succeeds or fails, on resolve), `done`('this will run if the $.get succeeds' - weird name for it), `fail`(fail) conditions.

```
 var promise = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'www.foo.com',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: muhData
  });
  promise.complete(function(d) {
    console.debug("complete");
  }).fail(function(){
    console.error("failed!");
  }).done(function(d){
    console.log('Done');
  });
```

**tl;dr: Wut code do?**

Comment: If you downvote because it's obvious to you and I am missing something obvious - please throw a link to what I am missing here.

Comment: One should never downvote without commenting. It is antisocial behavior.

Comment: Did you read those docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

Comment: It's part of the ajax docs, not deferred.  Scroll down to `complete`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks guys. I am seeing I am seeing `complete`, `error`, and `success`, I am not seeing done anywhere - it seems to be deprecated. `you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done().` - is that the case?

Comment: P.S. I don't use jQuery ever - that probably shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.complete()`, `.done()` and `.fail()` are all jQuery-specific implementations that do not follow promise standards.  jQuery also supports `.then()` an in jQuery 3.x they attempted to make `.then()` be compliant with the promise standard.  What I'd suggest you do is this:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'www.foo.com',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: muhData
  }).then(function(d) {
    console.debug("complete");
  }, function() {
    console.error("failed!");
  });
```

Or, if you're forced to an older version of jQuery and want standard's compliant behavior, you can do this:

```
 Promise.resolve($.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'www.foo.com',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: muhData
  })).then(function(d) {
    console.debug("complete");
  }).catch(function() {
    console.error("failed!");
  });
```

This casts/absorbs a jQuery promise into a standard promise so you can then use standard `.then()` and `.catch()` logic with it and have no surprises on how it works.

---

Here's more info on `.complete()`, `.done()` and `.fail()` from the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

`.complete()` is deprecated and `.always()` should be used instead.  This is called whether the promise fulfills or rejects (e.g. it's always called).

`.fail()` is analagous to `.catch()` in that it gets called when the promise rejects (though not identical in all respects).

`.done()` is analagous to the first argument passed to `.then()` in that it gets called when the promise fulfills.

Honestly, I don't think it is worth it to use jQuery promise logic directly because these days you are likely to have industry standard logic elsewhere in your app and it's quite a pain to have two slightly different implementations in use.  For simple things with jQuery ajax, I just stick with `.then()` on a jQuery promise.  For more involved things with nested or chained promises, I cast to a standard promise with `Promise.resolve()` so then I know the exact behavior it will have in all circumstances and it will work like all the other promises in my code.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a ton.