# How to execute multiple ajax calls asynchronously in one synchronous block (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, jquery-deferred

I know how to execute multiple ajax calls at once using $.when.
E.g.:

```
$.when( d1, d2 ).done(function ( v1, v2 ) {
    console.log( v1 ); // "Fish"
    console.log( v2 ); // "Pizza"
})
```

However, I want to use this in a method so that I can use it multiple times to return a value (e.g.

```
function getDataFor(list) {
    var data = [];

    $.when(d1(list), d2(list)).done(function (v1, v2) {
        console.log(v1);
        console.log(v2);

        data = [v1, v2];
    });

    return data;
}
```

What is the proper format for this? Also, is it essentially useless to use .then over .done in the above example unless I plan on having another promise follow that one?

**edit**: I do not feel that this is a duplicate question. Although I understand why it seems like that, I was really just looking to know if there was an out-of-the-box or library-based (e.g., jquery/bluebird) wrapper like .NET's WaitAll method which takes a set of asynchronous calls and blocks the thread until they are all completed. I've accepted that this isn't possible, but I don't feel it is a duplicate.

Comment: your code above will never work because `return data;` will always run before the ajax calls complete, and therefore `data` won't be populated. Anything you want to happen after the ajax calls complete, and which relies on data that they return, _must_ be triggered via either the "done" or "then" callbacks. What you _could_ do, is have your getDataFor method return the Promise which is returned by $.when, so that outside code can attach its own .then  / .done callbacks to that. You can have as many of those callbacks as you like attached to a promise.

Comment: I know it won't work. I'm asking how to perform something with the intended effect of that example. I want that block to essentially act as one which has async: false as a property. There are a lot of arrays that don't change after initialization at the top of this legacy code, and they're all calling synchronous methods currently. There are too many dependencies as-is for me to try to chain 15 of them together in the given timeline, so I was just trying to at least get rid of a few of them by merging them together. I could do away with this by just setting them as global variables, but.. :(

Comment: even if you set them global, if you try to use them before they're ready you'll have a problem. And it's impossible to know whether they're ready except within the callback. If you're currently relying on synchronous-ness to make things work, then some refactoring is inevitable unfortunately. Returning the promise is probably the best approach I can think of, then at least your calling code has got something to grab onto, and it can add its own .then callback to execute when everything has finished.

Comment: I know some refactoring is needed.. That's what I'm doing. I'm not trying to apply 0 effort. I know what we have time for so I just wanted to see if anything like this was possible. It's not. That's fine.

Comment: You can't use async calls and wrap them to make them synchronous.  Just can't be done.  Your `getDataFor()` function has to use async methods to return its result (either a callback or promise).  The answer yours has been marked a duplicate of shows you ALL the various possibilities.

Comment: Just do return `$.when(...)` and return the promise you already have.  The caller of your function, then uses `getDataFor(...).then(...)`.

Comment: I thought of that. That's not what I was asking so I don't feel that this is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible for a function to return multiple times, and [it's not possible to return any result variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1048572) before the ajax requests succeeded. You can however simply return a promise for the array of results - but for that you need to [use `then` instead of `done`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5436327/1048572) so that you can `return` from the callback. (Protip: just *never* use `done` or `fail`).

```
function getDataFor(list) {
    return $.when(d1(list), d2(list)).then(function (v1, v2) {
//  ^^^^^^                            ^^^^
        console.log(v1);
        console.log(v2);

        var data = [v1, v2];
        return data;
//      ^^^^^^
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about with returning multiple times. I just wanted to wait for several tasks to be completed before returning once like .Net's WaitAll method. I could do that with some messy timeouts, but I figured this was worth a shot. Thanks for the info about `then` btw!

Comment: @Dinerdo Maybe I just misunderstood the "*I can use it multiple times to return a value*" part of your question

Comment: Ah. I just wanted to use this method multiple times to return a value unique to each call (based on the list parameter). Poor wording on my behalf.