# Execute a function after N async calls in javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I have 7 async functions calls after which I need to execute a function.
Sample structure of code.

**Code**

```
<script>
(function(){

   f1();
   f2();
   f3();
   f4();
   f5();
   f6();
   f7();

   // execute final() when f1-f7 async function have executed. 
    //  All the function have ajax request
   final();

});
</script>
```

**My Current Approach**

```
<script>
    (function(){
       var finalExecuted = false;
       f1();
       f2();
       f3();
       f4();
       f5();
       f6();
       f7();

       // execute final() when f1-f7 async function have executed. 
        //  All the function have ajax request

      setInterval(function(){ 
       if($.active == 0 && !finalExecuted) {
         final();
         finalExecuted = true;
       } },500); 

       });
 </script>
```

Is this the correct approach to do? All the function f1-f7 are different functions and fetch different values from API's.

Comment: How do your function indicate they are finished? Can/do they return a promise?

Comment: If they do, you can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436327/jquery-deferreds-and-promises-then-vs-done (though the accepted answer is for an out-of-date version, it's still relevant and there's lots of info in the other answers)

Comment: Promise.all or $.when()

Comment: you are using ajax requests, if you are using JQuery you will probably work with promises

Comment: @MarkMeyer no they don't return a promise, can we do it in jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach you've used is good, A solid approach of working with asynchronous functions would be the following :

you are using ajax requests, if you are using JQuery to make your AJAX requests then you are working with promises, here is a solution you can use :

Create an array of promises

```js
var myPromises = [f1(),f2(),f3(),f4(),f5(),f6(),f7()];
```

now that you have your array set up use Promise.all function

```js
Promise.all(myPromises).then(function(vals){
    // write your code here
});
```

Promise.all gets invoked once all your async tasks passed in the array have finished executing.

Comment: setInterval will go off every 500ms and check if it should run

Comment: thank you I've updated my answer I thought it was a setTimeout

Answer (score 2):

If your functions return a promise, use them.

Using `async/await`:

```js
(async function(){
       let res1 = await f1();
       let res2 = await f2();
       let res3 = await f3();
       ...

       if(res1 && res2 && res3 && ... && resN)
          final();
       });
```

Using `Promise`:

```js
let promise1 = f1(); // some Promise in f1()
let promise2 = f2();
...
let promises = [promise1, promise2, ...];
Promise.all(promises).then((res) => final());
```

If not? Why don't you use it? create a Promise in `onload` or `onreadystatechange` then do like above. Or you can try [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: this is a working solution, that would be great if each request depended on the previous one. It would be prefered to use Promise.all in case each request is independent