# Refactor nested promises to a chain of promises

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simplified this problem. I have 3 functions which I want to run with a 2 second delay between each. The following code is working:

```
        $.when(one()).done(function () {
            $.when(delay(2000)).done(function () {
                $.when(two()).done(function () {
                    $.when(delay(2000)).done(function () {
                        $.when(three()).done(function () {
                            console.log('finished');
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });

    function delay(ms) {
        var waitForDelay = new $.Deferred();
        setTimeout(function () {
            waitForDelay.resolve().promise();
        }, ms);
        return waitForDelay.promise();
    }

    function one() {
        console.log('one');
        return new $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
    }

    function two() {
        console.log('two');
        return new $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
    }

    function three() {
        console.log('three');
        return new $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
    }
```

However when I try to refactor it, it no longer waits for the delayed amounts of time:

```
one().done(delay(2000)).done(two).done(delay(2000)).done(three).done(function () {
    console.log('finished');
});
```

How can I refactor to chain these promises rather than nesting them? I want to use jQuery for older browser compatibility.

Comment: _"older browser compatibility"_... how old?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice would be to not use jQuery's weird *promise-like* data structures at all.

Have your functions return an actual [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (either explicitly or by making them [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)) and `await` each step in the chain.

```js
const delay = (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));

// an async function implicitly returns a promise
const one = async () => {
  console.log("one");
}

// or you can return one manually
const two = () => {
  console.log("two");
  return Promise.resolve();
}

const three = async () => {
  console.log("three");
}

// await each step in an async function (an async IIFE in this case)
(async () => {
  await one();
  await delay(2000);
  await two();
  await delay(2000);
  await three();
  console.log("finished");
})();
```

You can also use `.then()` if you prefer that style

```js
// Convenience function so you don't repeat yourself
const waitTwoSeconds = () => delay(2000);
one()
  .then(waitTwoSeconds)
  .then(two)
  .then(waitTwoSeconds)
  .then(three)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("finished");
  });
```

---

If you *must* use jQuery, it doesn't really look much different

```js
function delay(ms) {
  var d = $.Deferred();
  setTimeout(d.resolve, ms);
  return d.promise();
}

function one() {
  console.log("one");
  return $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
}

function two() {
  console.log("two");
  return $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
}

function three() {
  console.log("three");
  return $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
}

function waitTwoSeconds() {
  return delay(2000);
}

one()
  .then(waitTwoSeconds)
  .then(two)
  .then(waitTwoSeconds)
  .then(three)
  .then(function() {
    console.log("finished");
  });
```

```html
<!-- Note jQuery 1.8 was the first to have chainable deferreds -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I've used `.then()` instead of `.done()` because the latter [does not chain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15694010/283366) and using `$.when()` is unnecessary when `.then()` is available.

Comment: that's a nice solution but i want to know how to do it with jquery. it sounds like my issue may be due to jQuery promises not behaving like regular promises?

Comment: @mulllhausen you know jQuery is just JavaScript, right?

Comment: of course. But then why do you say "jQuery's weird promise-like data structures"? You make it sound like jQuery is not using javascript promises. I haven't looked into it. Is that correct?

Comment: @mulllhausen because it's not. jQuery's Deferred object might act like a promise but it is a custom implementation. In any case, I've added a jQuery version to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from Phil's answer, here is a solution compatible with older browsers.

First, change the `delay()` function to return a function:

```
function delay(ms) {
    return function() {
        var waitForDelay = new $.Deferred();
        setTimeout(function () {
            waitForDelay.resolve().promise();
        }, ms);
        return waitForDelay.promise();
    }
}
```

All other functions stay the same as in the question.

Finally replace the `.done()`s with `.then()`s to make them chain:

```
one().then(delay(2000)).then(two).then(delay(2000)).then(three).then(function () {
    console.log('finished');
});
```